# App.config setting not updating web service end point

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a web service reference added. In the app.config, it is registered as follows:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <Project.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Project"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://myurl:8080/FileSystemIOService</value>
      </setting>
    </Project.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>
```

When I update the app.config URL, the project does not use the url. Instead it uses the Web Reference Url property setting of the web reference.

I have to change this property and recompile the code to change the Web Reference URL.

In other web service projects I have never had this issue. Changing the Url in the app.config correctly repointed the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a copy/paste error from the console (A) to the service project (B).

Project B settings then looked like

```
<applicationSettings> 
    <ProjectA.Properties.Settings>  <-- here is the issue
      <setting name="Project" 
        serializeAs="String"> 
        <value>http://myurl:8080/FileSystemIOService</value> 
      </setting> 
    </ProjectA.Properties.Settings> 
 </applicationSettings>
```

and the web service could not find the overriding setting.